# Accessing services without pod (without istio envoy) from outside cluster through istio ingress rules in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Steps:
1. I have created 2 namespaces (ns1 and ns2).
2. in ns1, i have deployed service where envoy proxy is enabled (istioctl kube-inject service.yaml)
2. in ns1, i have created istio ingress rules pointing to the service and i am able access it from outside the cluster.
3. in ns2, i havnt deploy any service because it is my shared namespace hence i have created headless service (External Name) which is pointing to the service deployed in ns1 namespace.

The problem is; i am not able to access service which is deployed in ns2 from outside the cluster. it is throwing 404 service not found.

did i miss anything here... do we have any other solution to address this?

Thanks,
Nikhil